# Por que usar nested classes em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, design-pattern, característica-linguagem

Volta e meia vejo coisas como:

```
class Teste
    class Foo

    end

    class Bar

    end
end
```

Usar classes dentro de classes... Alguém sabe me dizer pra quê isso? Não é melhor e mais correto usar módulos?

```
module Teste
    class Foo

    end

    class Bar

    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested classes serve para quando você precisa de uma classe que não precisa ou não deve ser acessível fora do contexto de outra classe.

```
class Comunidade
  class Pessoa
    def diga_ola
      'Olá!'
    end
  end

  def alguem_diga_ola
    joao = Pessoa.new
    joao.diga_ola
  end
end

Comunidade.new.alguem_diga_ola # Olá!
Pessoa.new.diga_ola # NameError: Unitialized constant Pessoa
```

Comment: é muito comum em linguagens dinâmicas, no python também acontece bastante.

Comment: Nested classes é ótimo para refatorar classes complexas.